# Передать функцию через child_process.fork

Tags: node.js

Есть ли какой то простой способ передать функцию между процессами запущенными через child_process.fork ?

Comment: Нет, никакого, конечно

Comment: ну от чего-же нету, в принципе есть

Comment: Это другая функция.  У неё другой контекст и всё остальное

Comment: Функция та-же, про контекст никто и не говорил, ибо его невозможно передать в принципе, по крайне мере не трогая кода V8, я знаком с устройством V8 и понимаю что из-за того что V8 изолирует код js в 'песочнице' его невозможно вытащить в текущем контексте даже через C/C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался как это сделать
Master Node

```
    const nos = require("child_process").fork("./worker.js");
function hello_world() {
    "use strict";
    var str1 = "Hello";
    var str2 = "World";
    function add_word(s1, s2) {
        var ret = s1 + " " + s2;
        return ret;
    }
    return add_word(str1, str2);
}

nos.send({function: hello_world.toString()});
```

Slave Node

```
process.on("message", function (msg) {
    "use strict";
    var fn = new Function(msg.function.toString().match(/\{([\s\S]*)\}/gi));
    console.log("message:" + fn());
});
```